# Merge different coloured shapes w/ illustrator CS5

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I'm trying to merge 4 different coloured shapes so I can apply a warp to them.

By warp I mean; make them look like there going off into the distance.

However, pathfinder turns the shape into one colour.

Is there a way to merge the different coloured shapes?

Answer (score 1):

You can group different colored shapes... Object > Group

You should also be able to simply select the 4 different objects and apply your warp or transformation with the objects selected.

Pathfinder is not the tool you want to use if you have objects of differing appearance. Pathfinder assumes you want all the objects to have the same appearance but a different construction method.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using the 'Free Transform' tool.

I selected the colur blocks.

Then selected the free transform tool, clicked a corner, then pressed cmd + alt + shift then dragged it to my desired shape.

Comment: If your own solution solved it, feel free to mark it as the right answer.